# replace all special characters in column values of a SQL table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, special-characters, regexp-replace

I have a column (in a SQL table) with several entries containing special characters (ampersand, comma, forward slash, dash, and parenthesis).

Is there a simple way to remove all these special characters (within the entries of <COLUMN_NAME> in below example) and replace with a underscore character?

This is what I am trying with no success unfortunately:

```
          SELECT MBR_ID, MONTH, 
                 REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '[/&-(,)()]+', '_') as COLUMN_NAME
          FROM TABLE_NAME
```

The error I am getting is: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'.Appreciate any guidance here!

Comment: Consider using `TRANSLATE` instead, as it saves you some headaches with proper regex escaping (e.g. `TRANSLATE(COLUMN_NAME, '/&-,()', '______')`). Disclaimer: no idea what causes your actual problem and this is not necessarily a fix.

Comment: This worked Jeroen! Please add your solution below for me to accept your answer to my question above. I definitely appreciate the much more intuitive syntax of TRANSLATE :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert please write that in an answer, so it can be accepted.